# Awk in shell script

Tags: awk, ksh

```
#
# Script Name : extract_filename.ksh
#
#!/bin/ksh

FILE_TO_SPLIT="CR_WKLY_Sales_SC_ON.TXT"
FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(awk FILE_TO_SPLIT_AWK="$FILE_TO_SPLIT" -F'[_.]' '{print $1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5}')
echo "$FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW"
```

the following command is running fine in the unix command prompt and getting desired output

```
echo "CR_WKLY_Sales_SC_NC.txt" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5}'
```

[image]

I am trying to extract **CR_Sales_SC_ON.TXT** by eliminating "WKLY" from filename, what am doing wrong in the above script..?

Is there any other better way to supress **WKLY** string from **CR_WKLY_Sales_SC_ON.TXT** string in shell script..?

`WKLY` is for just show my example it can be anything, our requirement is extract supress string in between first occurance of "`_`" (underscore) and second occurance of "`_`" (underscore).

eg.

```
CR_MNTHLY_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_WKLY_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_YRLY_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_DLY_ITr_SC_NC.txt
```

desired output should be

```
CR_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_ITr_SC_NC.txt
```

Comment: In the future please try to include text output from console instead of image

Comment: What is `FILE_TO_SPLIT_AWK="$FILE_TO_SPLIT"` supposed to be doing? Where are you giving awk the input it is supposed to parse?

Comment: Please specify in what way the output from your script differs from your expectations. In my tests with your example script, `awk` actually complained about syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to remove one of the underscores too. Here's a solution using `sed`:

```
$ echo CR_WKLY_Sales_SC_ON.TXT | sed 's/WKLY_//'
CR_Sales_SC_ON.TXT
```

Comment: WKLY is for just show my example it can be anything , our requirement is extract supress string in between first occurance of "_" (underscore) and second occurance of "_" (underscore).

eg. 

CR_MNTHLY_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_WKLY_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_YRLY_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_DLY_ITr_SC_NC.txt

desired output should be

CR_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_ITr_SC_NC.txt

Comment: @Sumanth then please edit your question and explain that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your actual problem is how you pass the string to be transformed to your `awk` call in the script. This is the reason for @terdon's question on what this `FILE_TO_SPLIT_AWK="$FILE_TO_SPLIT"` is supposed to mean.

One of the correct ways to do it would be like

```
FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(echo "$FILE_TO_SPLIT" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5}')
```

Also, since you want the filename suffix (in your case `.txt`) to be retained in your output, which your command-line example does not, you should

- either not include the period `.` in your list of field separators, or
- also print the last field

so either

- `awk -F'_' '{print $1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5}'`, or
- `awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5"."$6}'`

Anyway, if you want to be independent of the actual number of "_"-separated fields and only want to cout out the second one, the following example should work:

```
FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(echo "$FILE_TO_SPLIT" | awk '{match($0,"^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([[:print:]]*)$",a); print a[1]"_"a[3]}')
```

**Addendum**

If you want to avoid context switching due to use of the pipe, you can first write the filename to be transformed to a temporary file and have `awk` operate on that file instead of an in-memory variable.

```
echo $FILE_TO_SPLIT > tmpfile.txt
FILE_TO_SPLIT_NET=$(awk '{match($0,"^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([[:print:]]*)$",a); print a[1]"_"a[3]}' tmpfile.txt)
```

Then, however, (and of course depending on your particular use case) you might want to write all "raw" filenames to one file, have `awk` operate on that file, and read the result line-wise to process all transformed file names.

Comment: FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\(^[^_]*\)_[^_]*\(.*\)/\1\2/') is working, but can we do it without **echo** like below


FILE_TO_SPLIT=$1 | sed 's/_[^_]*_/_/'

Comment: We _may_ be able to find a solution, but you would need to specify _why_ you want to avoid the `echo $... | command` approach.

Comment: I assuming it will be switching context when we use **echo**, just to eliminate that  context switching, please correct me if am wrong and thank you all guys for your help and patience..

Comment: I see. The "problem" is that you are using `ksh`, in a `bash`, you could use a "here-string" like in `FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(awk ' .... ' <<< $FILE_TO_SPLIT)` ...

Comment: is there any other way we can achieve without context switching..

Comment: If no one else came up with a better idea, you may have to write the filename to a temporary file and have `awk` run on that file instead, see edited answer ...

Answer (score 0):

is `awk` mandatory ?

`sed` is fited for the task, using intuitive substitution

```
sed -e 's/\(^[^_]*\)_[^_]*\(.*\)/\1\2/' u
CR_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_ITr_SC_NC.txt
```

where `u` is your file (or input).

for a single variable

```
FILE_TO_SPLIT_NEW=$(echo "$FILE_TO_SPLIT" | sed -e 's/\(^[^_]*\)_[^_]*\(.*\)/\1\2/')
```

sed's syntax :

- `/\(^[^_]*\)_[^_]*\(.*\)/` this filter pattern1_pattern2_rest where pattern and rest have no `_`.

  - `[^_]*` stand for "anything but underscore, any number of time".
  - pattern1 and rest are assign to variable `\(...\)`
- `/\1\2/` expand variable
- `-e` can be omited for a single substitution

Comment: Thank you for in depth explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps

```
cut -d_ -f1,3- file
```

Set delimiter `-d_` and output `-f` fields 1 and 3 onwards `1,3-`

Output

```
CR_In2_SC_NC.txt
CR_Sales_ST_NC.txt
CR_In2_ST_NC.txt
CR_ITr_SC_NC.txt
```

On a variable/string

```
cut -d_ -f1,3- <<<"CR_Banana_IN2_SC_NC.txt"
```

Or

```
echo "CR_Banana_IN2_SC_NC.txt" | cut -d_ -f1,3-
```